# PHP difference in array parameters

Tags: php, parameters, type-hinting

In PHP 7, I want only arrays to be in the parameters, but what is the difference between:

```
function exampleA(array $a, array $b)
{

}
```

and

```
function exampleB($a = array(), $b = array())
{

}
```

Not sure which I should be using.

Comment: Second option is setting the default value to an empty array. If you call that function without params, $a and $b will be empty arrays

Comment: `function exampleA(array $a, array $b)` explicitly expects an array, and will throw an error if the parameter passed in is not an array.
`function exampleB($a = array(), $b = array)` doesn't care what the types of $a and $b are, and will set them to empty arrays if they are not passed in.

Answer (score 1):

The comments are good but I guess we need an answer.

`exampleA()` using `array $a` forces the arguments to be of type `array` and if not it throws a catchable error:

```
exampleA();
exampleA(1, 'A');
```

Both yield:

> Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to exampleA() must be of the type array, none given, called in file on line X and defined in file on line X

Whereas in `exampleB()` using `$a = array()`:

```
function exampleB($a = array(), $b = array())
{
    var_dump(get_defined_vars());
}
```

Sets default values to empty arrays when no values are supplied:

```
exampleB();
```

Yields:

```
array(2) {   ["a"]=>   array(0) {   }   ["b"]=>   array(0) {   } }
```

However, when values are supplied those values are used regardless of type:

```
exampleB(1, 'A');
```

Yields:

```
array(2) {   ["a"]=>   int(1)   ["b"]=>   string(1) "A" }
```